# Regex conditional search javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need some help with javascript

I need to search **(p|t|k)** and **(b|d|g)** in a text paragraph taken from a textarea then mark with `<b>`**(b|d|g)**`</b>` only if they are preceded or followed by one of the letters **(p|t|k)**

examples:

**b**p **b**

t**b**

**b**p

fb

The only thing I was able to do is mark both and search it by myself but if someone could help me with this would be great

Comment: In the first example, should the b be bolded instead of the p's?

Comment: @xdhmoore yep mb, i'm going to read  that, thank you!

Comment: Also shouldn't b in the last example be bolded?

Comment: `"kb".replaceAll(/(?:(?<=[ptk] *)([bdg]))|(?:([bdg])(?= *[ptk]))/g,'<b>$&</b>')`.

Comment: My other attempts didn't completely work, so I removed them. Hopefully this one does and is helpful. Anyway, that's my final attempt.

Comment: @xdhmoore I really appreciate your help , thank you very much!